# Remove user space quota in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, users, quota

I'm trying to install [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com) but I only have 1.5GB (EDIT: I forgot to mention this is what the Unity3D installer says, but I have also had problems with downloading things of large sizes) free space left in my home directory. How can I remove/extend my user quota?

output of `df -h` as requested:

```
amohr@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       29G   27G  1.6G  95% /
udev            2.5G  4.0K  2.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           993M  936K  992M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.5G  4.4M  2.5G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3       293G   30G  264G  11% /host
```

I used a 300GB partition for Ubuntu and haven't installed much.. there is no way I can be running out of space.

Comment: If you're not the administrator, you can't: ask your sysadmin instead. If you _are_ the sysadmin, why do you have a quota on your account? :)

Comment: Is this your personal machine? Who controls the user quota? How are you going to install Unity3D anyway? It doesn't have a Linux version as far as I know.

Comment: @JosephR. I don't know if I'm sysadmin. How do I tell? When I installed Ubuntu this is the only account I created...

Comment: @terdon yes its my personal machine. Installing Unity3D using wine

Comment: If its your machine, there shouldn't be any quota. Are you sure you have not simply run out of space on the partition? Please post the output of `df -h`. You might also be interested in [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26140).

Comment: Added and seen it :)

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you are using Wubi and indeed you are running out of space in your `/` partition.

Comment: I suppose I am using Wubi, forgot about the 30GB install size. How do I extend it? I think it said it could be done when I was installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a quota problem: your root (and only) partition is full. You haven't set up your system with a 300GB partition, you've set it up with a 30GB root partition. That's ok to install common applications but small if you want to install a lot of applications or if you have more than a couple of GB of data.

There is a lot of room on `/host` that you might be able to use. You can put some directories there and make a symbolic link where it needs to be.

Alternatively, you may want to repartition your disk. You mention Wubi in a comment; I don't think you can extend the Wubi root volume. Wubi is kind of restricted and not very useful; consider doing a proper installation (with a larger volume) instead.

Comment: I ended up doing this instead, and upgrading to 13.04. I did find a way of increasing the wubi disk space. It involved making a new disk, copying everything over and deleting the old disk.